# How to pass an async method as an action?

Tags: c#, linq, hangfire

I've this method:

```
public class Publish
{
    public async Task NowAsync(bool isFinal)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

and I want to pass it as a parameter here instead of `() => Console.WriteLine()`:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("name", () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
```

`AddOrUpdate` method accepts a parameter of type `Expression<Action>`

How can I do it? thanks.

Comment: `var isFinal = true; RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("name", async () => await NowAsync(isFinal));`

Comment: Maybe [This way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511466/whats-the-method-signature-for-passing-an-async-delegate)?

Comment: @FCin "Async lambda expressions cannot be converted to expression trees"

Comment: @Blendester You didn't specify that this was for Entity-Framework. Entity-Framework doesn't support this at all.

Comment: @BradleyUffner But this is not for entity framework.. I want to run that method in Hangfire

Comment: Ahh, sorry for the assumption, I'll remove the tag.  I've added the "Hangfire` tag for you instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with [hangfire 1.6](https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html) (which is 1.5 years old at this moment) you can pass async methods (methods that return `Task`) to `AddOrUpdate` without converting them to synchronous methods (to `Action`):

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("name", () => NowAsync(true), (string) null);
```